# Highchart-ng change the chart type in drilldown

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I need to change the chart type after one level of drill down, but the drill down level must remain the same.

I am looking something similar to

`http://jsfiddle.net/VEaLz/` but for highcharts-ng.

Specifically the part that emulates:

```
  $("#container").highcharts().series[0].update({ type: 'column' });
```

So far I have been successful at creating multi level drill down. But each time I try to change the chart type, the drill-down resets

Comment: You could set type of series used in drilldown like here: http://jsfiddle.net/VEaLz/25/ It is based on data and chart configuration, so it should work with angular. Will that work for you?

Comment: Thing is I cant use `$("#container").highcharts().series[0].update({ type: 'column' });` from higcharts-ng

Comment: The solution I have provided for you is not relaying on that function - to be clear I have removed the button and the function: http://jsfiddle.net/VEaLz/26/